# SQL Join from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `segment` with `segmentCode, Description, pst-active, ...`. I also have a table `subarea` with `FK SegmentCode, deelgebiedID, Deelgebied, ...`. Now I would like to select all the segments but also the subareas of the segment. My ideal array would be

```
segments[[segmentCode, Description, ..., [array with subareas data]],[segmentCode, Description, ..., [array with subareas data]]]
```

How can I do this in a query? I've tried this but it's just given me segments duplicates ..

Comment: Maybe do you want a simple JOIN?

Comment: Yes, but I don't have a lot experience with joins, could you help me?

Comment: do you want to get subarea details like array ah?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this:

Either do one select statement on the database that holds all the required information and build your array from that. The statement would looke something like `SELECT * FROM segment seg JOIN subarea sub ON seg.segmentCode = sub.SegmentCode ORDER BY seg.segmentCode, sub.deelgebiedID;`. You would then have to iterate through the results, keep track of the segmentCode and create a new segment object whenever the segmentCode changes. While it does not change you simply add the subareas to that object (or create an array).

The other way is to split the process in several selects. First get the segments with `SELECT * FROM segment seg ORDER BY seg.segmentCode;`. Then loop over the retrieved segments and fetch the subareas for each: `SELECT * FROM subarea sub WHERE sub.SegmentCode = PARAMETER ORDER BY sub.deelgebiedID;`.

Which approach to choose in your situation is a trade-off between performance (one database statement usually is much better) vs. memory consumption and code complexity.

Comment: There will be pretty same memory consumption in both cases. So I would recommended to use the first approach, because there are a lot of issues for db queries in loops.

Comment: The problem is that I have fields with the same names in both of the tables... Like 'map' .. How can I fix this?

Comment: You could display only the columns you need and you could rename columns in the query like this: `SELECT seg.segmentCode, seg.Description as MyRenamedSegmentDescription, sub.Deelgebied as Foo FROM segment seg JOIN subarea sub ON ...`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this one.

```
SELECT s.segmentCode, s.Description, a.* 
  FROM segment s 
  LEFT JOIN subarea a 
    ON (s.segmentCode = a.SegmentCode);
```

I hope it works for you.